# Remove Element Arraylist and Shift Over Empty Space

Tags: java, arraylist

Have an arraylist and want to remove an element passed in comparing using .equals. Remove this object and shift elements over empty space. If no element I would return false.

```
public boolean remove(E obj) {

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: ok. what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to return a boolean do this:

```
public boolean remove(E obj) {

ArrayList<Object> myList = new ArrayList();

for(Object object: myList){
if(object.equals(obj){
return true;
}}
return false;
}
```

If you want to return a list without the target then do this:

```
public ArrayList<Object> remove(E obj) {

ArrayList<Object> myList = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<Object> answerList = new ArrayList();

for(Object object: myList){
if(object.equals(obj){
continue;
}
answerList.add(object);
}
return answerList;
}
```

Comment: How would you get it to shift over the empty space after it is removed?

Comment: What do you mean specifically?

If you want to alter the position of elements whilst iterating over it then that can't be done. You make a new list in the format you want. The compiler won't let you alter a list whilst iterating over it, you can act on the objects inside it sure, but not remove, move or add elements to the list you are currently iterating over. The reason for this is because it would lead to infinite loops and other strange issues, and luckily it is easy to just make a new list to work on instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove something from an ArrayList, the rest of the elements are moved left to fill in.  Since your List may not implement certain methods, it's important to place it in an ArrayList prior to calling.

```java
      List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30, 40, 50));


     // Then you can just remove the object.  It will return true if deleted or
     // false if not. Note, you need to cast the value to type Object if it's an
     // Integer, otherwise it will assume it is an index.

      System.out.println(list.remove((Object) 120)); // prints false
      System.out.println(list); // prints [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
      System.out.println(list.remove((Object) 40)); // prints true
      System.out.println(list); // prints [10 20, 30, 50]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
    public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListWrapper<String> wrapper = new ListWrapper<>(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3")));
        wrapper.print();
        System.out.println("REMOVE:" + wrapper.remove("2"));
        wrapper.print();
    }

    public static class ListWrapper<T> {
        private final ArrayList<T> list;

        public ListWrapper(ArrayList<T> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        public boolean remove(T obj) {
            boolean removed = list.remove(obj);
            list.trimToSize();
            return removed;
        }

        public void print() {
            System.out.println("LIST: " + list);
        }
    }
}
```